# Flutter app with multi Firebase (for multi environment)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I'm doing an app with `Flutter` which has `Firebase` Authentification
But as i want to have a "Firebase Authentification for development", i created another `GCP/Firebase` project to get that.

Doing this make me handle 2 `google-services.json` and 2 `keytools SHA-1`

For `google-services.json` file, i put one where they suggest to [`android/app/`] and the other on [`android/app/src/`], but do `Gradle` can know which one it has to choose ?

And for the keytools, i only can generate one, do you have any advise for this ?

Thank you for your future answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you have to handle this by using [flavors](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors)

You have to create a folder for each environment but there are two good tutorials about how to setup this :

- [First](https://medium.com/@matt.goodson.business/separating-build-environment-configurations-in-flutter-with-firebase-doing-it-the-right-way-c72c3ad3621f)  without dart awareness
- [Second](https://medium.com/@LohaniDamodar/flutter-separating-build-environment-with-multiple-firebase-environment-92e40e26d275) with two dart files

Comment: Oh i didn't know about flavors, i'm going to look at this solution.

Thank you for your answer !

During those two month, i just took 2 keystore to separate the 2 firebase and i configure my CI/CD to select the right keystore